# server side include apache enable

Tags: .htaccess, server-side-includes, ssi

I am trying to enable SSI to use it in my site.
The first thing that i am want to do is just enable it and do an echo to verified if it work at all.

I have apache2, in the root directory there is SSI folder and inside that folder i made a .htaccess file that look like this:

```
Options +Includes
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

So now its supposed to enable SSI. (right?)

in the SSI folder there is echo_ssi.shtml file, contain:

```
<!--#echo var="DATE_GMT" -->
```

when i am open echo_ssi.shtml in the browser, nothing happen.
I suppose to get time and date in GMT...

What im doing wrong in the SSI enable configuration?
There is somthing else that im need to do / add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the **server cash**. need to clean the cash on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you scanned the [Apache Module mod_include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html) and the [Apache SSI Tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html) documentation?

You need to ensure that you are loading mod_include.

If you have then with the `.htaccess` lines that you list then

```
<HTML><BODY><!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" --></BODY></HTML>
```

should return a page with the date & time on it.

Comment: @lolo Use [LoadModule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule) directive.

Comment: If your LAMP stack is Debian/Ubuntu, check that you have the symlink for mod_include in `/etc/apache2/sites_enabled`.  Or just look at a phpinfo() report. There should be a section **apache2handler** which will list off the modules loaded.  If this doesn't exist then you are probably running on a shared service and you need to talk to your service provider